# Was Satan an Angel

Tags: history, satan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where in the Bible does it say that Lucifer is an angel?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/where-in-the-bible-does-it-say-that-lucifer-is-an-angel)
>   [Of what nature is Satan?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/of-what-nature-is-satan)

Most people refer to the following scripture as support for the fact that Satan was an angel, but I do not see that explicitly stated.

Isaiah 14:12-14
    "How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations! For thou hast said in thine heart, I will ascend into heaven, I will exalt my throne above the stars of God: . . . I will be like the most High."

So my question is is Lucifer Satan? Was Satan an Angel?

Comment: Some questions like this have already been asked and answered: [Are Lucifer and Satan different beings?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/201/are-lucifer-and-satan-different-beings), [Of what nature is Satan?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/of-what-nature-is-satan), [Where in the Bible does it say that Lucifer is an angel?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/where-in-the-bible-does-it-say-that-lucifer-is-an-angel)