# Who are the seven princes of hell?

Tags: satan, hell

Who are the seven princes of Hell? 
I think I know them but I am not 100%. I believe they are Belial, Satan, Beelzebub, Asmodeus, Laviathan, Mammon, Belphegor, Lucifer. 
Could someone tell me if I am right and if so what hell are they in charge of please. If I am wrong could you tell me with their roles please.

Comment: According to what tradition?  Of these, only Beelzebub, Lucifer, and Satan actually appear in Scripture, and they all seem to be the same person

Comment: You may want to check out this question: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/of-what-nature-is-satan/12031#12031

Comment: It all I can remember from my childhood when I went to bible school and my younger sister. That what I got when I read information about them but my old bible teacher told me that they are all different angels or demons.

Answer (score 13):

According to [Peter Binsfeld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Binsfeld), you've got the list right.  He made the list in 1589; there was no support for that theory before then, and there has been very little support for that theory since.

As far as I know, there is no Christian tradition which adheres to there being seven princes of Hell.  More than that, at least the names "Lucifer" and "Satan" refer to the same entity.  Mammon is synonymous with greed or money (`Matthew 6:24`), but is sometimes personified also.  Asmodeus and Belphegor aren't even mentioned in the Bible.

Peter's list seems to have been extrapolated from the 7 deadly sins, without any scripture to back up his list.  Here it is.

- Lucifer: pride
- Mammon: greed
- Asmodeus: lust
- Leviathon: envy
- Beelzebub: gluttony
- Satan: wrath
- Belphegor: sloth

Comment: Leviathon is mentioned in [Job 41](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job+41&version=NIV) and [Isaiah 27:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%2027:1&version=NIV).

Comment: The leviathan of Job is an animal, not a demon. The description is physical -- teeth, scales, etc -- I don't see anything there to interpret this as a demon. The passage in Isaiah is not as clear, he appears to be using leviathan as a symbol for something or someone, but you could debate exactly what.

Comment: The idea of [seven levels](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6558-gehenna) of hell comes from rabbinic tradition, specifically the Babylonian Talmud (Soṭah 10b). This appears to have been used as the inspiration for [Dante's Purgatorio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins#Dante.27s_Purgatorio) and he appears to have combined this idea with the [7 deadly sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins). According to the jewish encyclopedia, Shab. 104 put forth the idea that there was an angel prince. Therefore an angel-prince for each level is a natural progression...

Comment: @JamesShewey Dante's works are full of kabbalistic imagery, I came across an article once that related them to hermeticism, I wish I could find it for you now.

Comment: interesting. So as Satan is a wrathful character, perhaps Belphegor is plain lazy? With this assortment the only thing missing is Snow White;-P

Comment: Asmodeus is in Tobit 3:7–11; it's the demon who killed Sara's seven husbands when they tried to consummate their marriage to her, so it makes sense that such a spirit would be associated with lust.

Comment: Belphegor, in turn, is mentioned in Numbers 25:1–5, though he is called _Baalpeor_ in the KJV.